# Show html elements on same line

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular, typescript

```
<p [innerHTML]="viewTransactions | fdContent"></p>
<a [attr.href]="myLink" [innerHTML]="statementsLbl | fdContent"></a>
```

How do I get the link to show right after the viewTransactions rather than on a new line?

Comment: Could you describe a little more your problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this, a simple and reliable one is using a flex-container:

```
<div style="display: flex">
 <p [innerHTML]="viewTransactions | fdContent"></p>
 <a [attr.href]="myLink" [innerHTML]="statementsLbl | fdContent"></a>
</div>
```

Have a look at the [Flexbox specification](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) to learn more.

Comment: Awesome. That worked. Is there a way to add a space in between the two?

Comment: You can put a margin on your a tag:
`<a style="margin-left: 5px" [attr.href]="myLink" [innerHTML]="statementsLbl | fdContent"></a>`
If you want to do more web development you should learn about css: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basics. cheers.